# JSHint globals option is not working in .jshintrc

Tags: javascript, jshint, adobe-brackets

I'm using [Brackets 1.2](http://brackets.io) and the extension [brackets-jshint](https://github.com/cfjedimaster/brackets-jshint). Here is my `.jshintrc` in my project root:

```
{
    'bitwise': true,
    'boss': true,
    'camelcase': true,
    'curly': true,
    'devel': true,
    'eqeqeq': true,
    'eqnull': true,
    'expr': true,
    'forin': true,
    'iterator': false,
    'latedef': true,
    'multistr': false,
    'nocomma': true,
    'noarg': true,
    'noempty': true,
    'nonbsp': true,
    'nonew': true,
    'quotmark': 'single',
    'undef': true,
    'unused': true,
    'globals': {
        '$': true,
        'document': true,
        'jQuery': true,
        'window': true
    }
}
```

The `globals` option is not working and the white list of global variables are still being warned by JSHint.

I also tried these:

```
globals: true
jquery: true
devel: true
```

But no success, `$`, `jquery`, `window`, `document` and `alert` are still warned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must replace **single** quotes with **double** in `.jshintrc` : ) This answer is to short, so I’m going to add a little explanations …

Just open **Debug » Developers tools** try to validate some JavaScript file – you can see in debug console

> JSHint: error parsing /project/path/.jshintrc. Details: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '

As method responsible for reading .jshintrc looks like:

```
try {
    config = JSON.parse(removeComments(content));
} catch (e) {
    console.error("JSHint: error parsing " + file.fullPath + ". Details: " + e);
    result.reject(e);
    return;
}
```

**JSON.parse** implements http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt - according to [ECMAScript Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12) and there is no place for `'` .

From **rfc 4627** only valid structure to describe JSON is

> ```
> string = quotation-mark *char quotation-mark
>
> char = unescaped /
>        escape (
>            %x22 /          ; "    quotation mark  U+0022
>            %x5C /          ; \    reverse solidus U+005C
>            %x2F /          ; /    solidus         U+002F
>            %x62 /          ; b    backspace       U+0008
>            %x66 /          ; f    form feed       U+000C
>            %x6E /          ; n    line feed       U+000A
>            %x72 /          ; r    carriage return U+000D
>            %x74 /          ; t    tab             U+0009
>            %x75 4HEXDIG )  ; uXXXX                U+XXXX
>
> escape = %x5C              ; \
>
> quotation-mark = %x22      ; "
> ```

Comment: It might be worth adding a little more explanation as to why that code throws an error when it encounters single quotes.

Comment: Oh yes. Thank you. Before this, I tried without quotes on the option names and it is not working too. However it was not working only for those variable settings and other options are fine.

Comment: @Sithu These configuration files use [Json](http://json.org) format, which only supports double quote, not the full JS syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have disabled JSLint, the linter that comes with Brackets by default.
You can do so by adding this snippet to your brackets.json (open via `Debug > Show Preferences File`):

```
"language": {
    "javascript": {
        "linting.prefer": "JSHint",
        "linting.usePreferredOnly": true
    }
}
```